Contar todos los caracteres de un conjunto python
Hola tengo un conjunto en python el cual es el siguiente:
{'hola', 'que', 'tal', 'estas?'}

Y me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para contar todos los caracteres que hay

Para esto utilizamos join para juntar todas las palabras del conjunto en una sola cadena y luego con len podremos contar los caracteres de esta
conjunto = {'hola', 'que', 'tal', 'estas?'}
cadena = ''.join(conjunto)

total_caracteres = len(cadena)

print("El total de caracteres en el conjunto es:", total_caracteres)

